# Stages of Compassion in Mahayana

Tags: reference-request, mahayana, sutras, compassion

**Dear friends**, I am looking for references pertaining to the notion of the *Four Stages of Compassion* in the Mahayana traditions.

Thank you for your kind and generous help, may you all be well and safe.

> If you ask what is ‘great compassion,’ it is unstinting loving kindness toward all sentient beings, when there are actually no sentient beings. That is called great compassion.
>
> The Buddha (Perfection of Wisdom Sutra in Ten Thousand Lines)
>
> [Tweet by The Buddhist Society](https://twitter.com/buddhistsociety/status/1242096361388093441?s=19)

Answer (score 1):

In ~30 years of (western) Buddhism I haven't come across "four stages of compassion". However, there are:

- the four [Brahmaviharas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmavihara) and
- five stages of cultivating compassion, introduced by Buddhaghosa in the Visuddhimagga and explained for example in [Wildmind](https://www.wildmind.org/blogs/on-practice/guided-compassion-meditation-karuna-bhavana).

For "great compassion" maybe see [Mahakaruna](https://www.dhammawiki.com/index.php/Mahakaruna). The Indians tend to put a "maha" before a word to mark the term as informed by the experience of liberation.

Comment: "Maha" is used as a prefix which translates as "greater".